# Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded but not convergent sequence. Prove that $(x_n)$ has two subsequences converging to different limits.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded but not convergent sequence. Prove that $(x_n)$ has two subsequences converging to different limits.

My attempt is: 
Since the sequence is bounded , there exists $M>0$ such  that $x_n \in [-M,M]$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since the sequence does not converge to $x$, there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $ \forall N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $n \geq N$ such that $|x_n-x| \geq \epsilon_0$.

Then we have $x_n \in [-M,x-\epsilon_0] \cup x_n \in [x+\epsilon_0,M]$. By Bolzano-weierstrass theorem, there exists a convergent subsequence in the two intervals.

Is my proof valid? ${}{}$

Comment: No, since all the terms of the sequence might be $\leqslant x-\epsilon_0$.

Comment: No, this is not valid. What tells you that there are infinitely many terms in each of the two intervals of the union?

Comment: *First* choose $x$ so that it is a subsequential limit point of $(x_n)$. Then choose a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ that is bounded away from $x$. Finally, choose a subsequence of $(x_{n_k})$ that converges...

Comment: I haven learn subsequential limit point of a sequence, so I don know what are you talking about.@DavidMitra

Comment: @julien: so what guarantee that I can find infinitely many terms in the two intervals ?

Comment: You don't need that to prove the result. See Herng Yi's answer.

Comment: From what I understand, suppose the subsequence $(x_{n_i})$converge to $x$. Then by definition of convergence, we have $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n_i > N , |x_{n_i}-x|<\epsilon$. Then I get blur

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use Bolzano-Weierstrass to extract a subsequence $x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}, \dotsc$ that converges to some $a$. Since $x_1, x_2, \dotsc$ does not converge to $a$, there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for each positive integer $N$, there exists some $j(N) > N$ such that $|x_{j(N)} - a| \geq \varepsilon$. Use Bolzano-Weierstrass to extract from $x_{j(1)}, x_{j^2(1)}, x_{j^3(1)}, \dotsc$ a subsequence $x_{k_1}, x_{k_2}, \dotsc$ that converges to some $b$. Clearly, $a \neq b$.

By the way, this method works for any $x_1, x_2, \dotsc$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which goes beyond what the OP intended.

Comment: ahh yes, let me insure that now, thanks! :)

Comment: $j^2(1) = j(j(1))$, which I guess is an example of what you meant by a "$j_m$".

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought it was a power.

Comment: Actually I not quite understand the answer

Comment: can @HerngYi elaborate ?

Comment: @Idonknow, I'll infer the object of your confusion from your comments to your question. As you said, my sequence $x_1, x_2, \dotsc$ converges to $a$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $i > N$, $|x_i - a| < \epsilon$. Intuitively, within any tiny neighborhood (radius $\epsilon$) of $a$, if I go far enough into the sequence (past $x_N$), the subsequent terms will all lie within that tiny neighborhood.

Comment: However, $x_1, x_2, \dotsc$ does *not* converge to $a$ so there exists *some* neighborhood of $a$ (radius $\varepsilon$, from my answer) such that no matter how far up the sequence I run, there will always be "erratic" terms that "jump" outside the neighborhood. My sequence $x_{j(1)}, x_{j^2(1)}, x_{j^3(1)}, \dotsc$ consists of some of these erratic terms.

Comment: but how can we make sure the two intervals $[-M,a-\epsilon]$ and $[a+\epsilon,M]$, one of them is not empty ?

Comment: Sorry if I myself got confused (lol), but my elaboration was for my answer. From what I understand of your approach (which is in the context of $\mathbb{R}$), your "$x_n$" are the "erratic terms" I mentioned that jump outside $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$. It is possible that the erratic terms all lie in one of your intervals $[-M, a - \epsilon]$ and $[a + \epsilon, M]$ while the other is empty. But it's ok because we only need *one* sequence from one of those intervals that converges to, say, $b$, because we already have a sequence that converges to $a \neq b$!

Comment: i thought if we want to use Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, we can only use it on sequence, but not subsequence? From what I know, sequence is defined as a function $f$ with domain $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: The subsequence $x_{j(1)}, x_{j^2(1)}, \dotsc$ is a sequence because it is a function $f$ with domain $\mathbb{N}$, where $f(i) = x_{j^i(1)}$. In essence, any subsequence can be turned into your "$f$" by "re-indexing" the terms back to $1, 2, 3, \dotsc$.

Answer (score 2):

- If a sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded, $a\le x_n \le b$ say, then it has at least one limit point $x$ with $a\le x\le b$ (Bolzano-Weierstraß) and
- a bounded sequence with exactly one limit point $x$ converges towards that limit point.

Therefore there must exist at least two distinct limit points and we can extract a converging sequence for each.

Just in case the second bullit point above is not clear: 
If $a\le x_n\le b$ for all $n$ and $x$ is not the limit of $x_n$, then  there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that infinitely many $x_n$ are outside $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$, hence there are infinitely many $x_n>x+\epsilon$ or infinitely many $x_n<x-\epsilon$, leading to at least one limit point $x'$ in $[x+\epsilon,b]$ or $[a,x-\epsilon]$. Thus if $x$ is a limit point but not the limit, there is another limit point $x'\ne x$.

Comment: I think the OP wants to prove the result without assuming your second bullet point, sort of a "from first principles" thing.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, valid, but could write it even clearer.

For each $N$ there is an $n$ such that $|x_n-x|\ge \epsilon_0$. Let such an $n$ be chosen for all $N$ and denote it by $k(N)$, for example. Thus we get a *subsequence* $(x_{k(1)},x_{k(2)},\dots)$ of $(x_n)$, which lies in $[-M,x-\epsilon_0]\cup [x+\epsilon_0,M]$, so this subsequence has a convergent subsequence, and the limit of that cannot be $x$.

Comment: Sorry but who is $x$?

Comment: This proves that if $x_n$ does not converge to $x$, then there is a convergent subsequence which does not converge to $x$. So you need a little more, i.e. to take $x$ to be a limit of some subsequence of $(x_n)$ in the first place.